# Querying for RecordType's DeveloperName throws error when generating code through tooling

Tags: soql, query, error, tooling-api, record-access-level

I get this error when querying for `DeveloperName` via the **`Tooling API`** even though I can perform the same query in the developer console with the same user.

> "No such column 'developername' on entity 'RecordType'"

1. `system.debug([select developername from recordtype]);//Error`
2. The same query worked well using Workbench.
3. `system.debug(Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('SomeRecordTypeName').getRecordTypeId());//Works Well`

I found no documentation either answer why this error is thrown.

Comment: Are you getting the error from the Tooling API or just from a debug using `Execute Anonymous`? Your post is a bit unclear on this point.

Comment: I'm getting it from the Tooling Api. Using Execute Anonymous i get no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for **[`RecordType`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_recordtype.htm)** specific to the `Tooling API`, you can see what fields are defined for access there. Specifically, it doesn't have `DeveloperName`, but rather `Name`.

Answer (score 1):

Querying Record Type data is not the same as querying Record Types through the Tooling API. Specifically, different fields are available in each instance. For the Tooling API, there is a Name attributes, which corresponds to the label, and the FullName attribute, which is the SObject type plus the API Name (ie 'Opportunity.Record_Type_Name'). It's important to note that you can only use FullName in a Tooling API query if a single record is returned. [Here's a link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_recordtype.htm) to the documentation for Record Types.